# Up and down keys to loop through array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array of colors. using the up and down arrow keys, I would like to loop through the array and add the current array value as a class to a div.

```
var colors = [ 
            "red", 
            "green",
            "blue"
];
```

I would like to store the present value as a variable and use the jQuery .addClass to append a the current class to a div. As a jQuery newcomer, any help here would be fantastic!

Comment: Just for giggles, can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, you have to post what you've written. We're not going to do your initial work for you.

Comment: Not because we want to laugh at your attempts, just so we can see what you're trying to do, and how we can help. And to verify you've made at least some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Looping an index counter with *Reminder* `%`

http://jsbin.com/howon/5/edit

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"],
    i = 0,
    n = colors.length;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
  var k = e.which; 
  if(k==38||k==40){
    i = (k==38? ++i : --i) <0? n-1 : i%n;
    $('#test').attr('class', colors[i]);
  } 
});
```

---

### 2. Manipulating internally the Array

Another interesting (**less complicated**) way to do it, without using a *current index counter*
is to **manipulate the Array** it-self by simply pushing the last key to the *first* position (or inverse, first to last) and always **get the [0] index key**:

http://jsbin.com/jojupo/3/edit

```
var colors = ["red", "green","blue"];

$(document).keydown(function(e){
  var k = e.which;
  if(k==38||k==40){
    if      (k==38) colors.push(colors.shift());
    else if (k==40) colors.unshift(colors.pop());
    $('#test').attr('class', colors[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Brock added another interesting and less *mathy* example.

Comment: Thank Roko, would it be possible to add a button click as an "or" statement to that?  For instance, if(k==38) or a button with the class of .up is clicked, then run the colors.push function?

Comment: @Brock Put the `colors.push` and `colors.unshift` lines into separate functions and call them whenever you need, on keyup, on a buttion click etc... like: `function nextColor(){colors.push(    colors.shift(); return color[0];}` and than you just call that function which will return the needed string: `nextColor(); // Green`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for registering the key presses, this should help get you started:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       alert( "up pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       alert( "right pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       alert( "down pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you along a bit, assuming your markup is

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

, the following JavaScript will loop through the color array and set the color.

```
var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  $myDiv.attr('class', colors[i]);
}
```

This, combined with the answer above about registering key presses, should get you most of the way there. I suggest using jQuery's .attr() method rather than jQuery's .addClass() method because otherwise you'll need to remove all previous classes each time you change the color.